# Mozilla Firefox memory Problem

Tags: memory, firefox, memory-management

When i run Firefox.. with the passage of time it continuously keeps on increasing its size in memory until it has consumed all the RAM.. no matter if i open and close 20 tabs or there is just one tab opened since start... then it is of course slow...

what is the problem and what should i do

i have

**Mozilla Firefox 3.6.3**

and the following plugins installed:

**Adblock Plus** | **Adobe DLM** | **BlockSite** | **Cooliris** |

**Flashgot** | **Fox Tab** | **Free Download Manager Plugin** | **Java Console** | **Java Quick Starter** |

**MultiRowBookmarks Toolbar** |

**OpenBookmarksInANewTab** |

**RealPlayerBrowserRecordPlayer Plugin**

plus like 50 bookmarks

Comment: How much RAM does the system have?  How much does Firefox end up consuming?  Firefox does have pretty hefty memory requirements these days...

Comment: 1 GB... with all the other stuff running i am always using 700-800 Mb
Firefox starts from 30Mb and goes to 350 Mb.. thats the max i have seen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two things I'd do would be to get rid of the Adobe DLM which is only needed for the installation of Adobe Flash (and shouldn't even be needed at all IMO) and RealPlayer.

I honestly thought that RealPlayer had died a well deserved death many years ago with it's unreliable and bloated Quicktime-esque player, and from what I can tell it is still around and doing quite well for itself.  I haven't seen a website that actually serves up video or audio in their horrific format since Adobe Flash cornered the YouTube market, and hopefully even that domination will be coming to an end soon.

Cooliris looks like a nice addon for artificially bloating memory requirements...

One thing you should try to do is [run Firefox in safe mode](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Safe+Mode) and disabling all addons.  This will allow you to see if it is one of your addons that is causing the memory usage.  If your problems go away then I'd recommend deleting all your addons, and reloading them one by one until your problem returns.

Answer (score 1):

You should try [FireFox 3.6.4](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/personal.html).

**Edit**:

Since you don't like my previous suggestion... maybe you'll like [this](https://support.mozilla.com/en-US/forum/1/659353?forumId=1&comments_threshold=0&comments_parentId=659353&comments_offset=80&comments_per_page=20&thread_style=commentStyle_plain#threadId696302).

Comment: i may but you need to stop being her advertising manager.. cuz upgrading is not solution when the current version worked fine since the last 10 plugins

Comment: @Moon There are many things at play. It sounds like a memory leak. Have any plug-ins been updated recently? Maybe one of the plug-ins was updated to work better with the new version of firefox and just happens to cause a memory leak on the old version. The only obvious thing to try is the new version of Firefox...

Comment: @Moon - upgrading to the latest version is almost **always** the first option when dealing with bugs in applications.

Answer (score 1):

I use this freeware, [Firemin 2.0.1.11](http://datumza.com/downloads/) :

> Firemin is a small app that eliminates all memory leaks in Firefox and keeps memory consumption at bay. 
>   The program runs in the system tray and constantly optimizes Firefox's memory by forcing it to release some of the memory it so greedily hangs on to. 
>   During our review, we ran Firefox with 8 opened tabs and just let it sit there for 30 minutes. 
>   During that time, memory consumption steadily increased to nearly 100 mb. We then activated Firemin and memory consumption decreased to 1-5 mb and remained within that range for the duration of the test.

Comment: Thanks decembre, this is hugely helpful.  I just installed Firemin and Firefox's memory usage went from 300 MB to 3 MB.  I'm very impressed.